# How can I connect a PHP container with nginx container by using docker-compose?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a simple LAMP stack in a Docker enviroment. It worked by running a third-party container `phpdockerio/php71-fpm:latest`, but I wanted a custom PHP container with XDebug installed, for the moment.

My problem is that, if I execute `docker-compose up`, the PHP container exit after startup before my webserver container can make usage of it. How can I successfully tell the PHP container to wait for a connection of my nginx container?

---

**Command-Line Output**

```
PS C:\playground> docker-compose.exe up
Starting playground_php_1
Starting playground_web_1
Attaching to playground_php_1, playground_web_1
playground_php_1 exited with code 0
playground_web_1 exited with code 1
```

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:latest

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]

CMD ["php", "-a"]
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./etc/php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './src:/usr/share/nginx/html'

  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - './etc/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
      - './src:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    depends_on:
      - php
```

---

**nginx configuration**

```
...
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
...
```

Comment: any time your containerized process exits, the container is considered to be stopped. If either of your processes are outputting anything on stdout/stderr before they exit, you can see that output by doing `docker logs <container_name_or_id>`

Comment: @programmerq Thanks, for the tipp. _:)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running, again, with my custom container. I changed the base image from `php` to `php-fpm`.

Next thing I did, was that I had to clear running containers and to delete already created images on my machine. Otherwise `docker-compose` would use the wrong/old container again.